# BOM randomly appears in JSON reply

Tags: php, json, curl, byte-order-mark

I'm implementing communication between two servers using JSON and cURL. The problem is, that sometimes there's BOM (byte order mark), appended before opening bracket in JSON reply. I've managed to trim it and successfully parse JSON string, but considering that JSON is generated by my own code, I've no idea, where does that BOM come from.

I'm using json_encode() to generate reply and header() + echo to print it, an as far as I cant tell, json_decode() does not produce any BOMs. Corresponding .php files are encoded in UTF-8 and have no BOM in them (according to Notepad++). Apart from cURL, I've also tried to perform requests using Chrome and python (urllib2). While Chrome does not register any BOM at all, python regularly fails to parse incoming JSON because of it.

So, is there some nuance in using echo, that somehow produces such a result? Where should I start looking for the source of the problem and what may be the solution?

Comment: Does your JSON contain any multi-byte characters? The only reason I can think of for a BOM appearing if you didn't explicitly put one there is if PHP for some reason determined that it was necessary for one to be there... Also, out of interest, what is/are the relevant PHP version(s)?

Comment: No, JSON replies do not contain multi-byte characters at all. And I'm using PHP 5.3.8

Comment: Are you dumping the JSON to a file at any point before echoing it?

Comment: This BOM originates in one of your PHP scripts before the opening `<?php` marker. Use a real text editor, failing that a hexeditor to find out where.

Comment: No, I am not saving JSON to file (therefore, not reading from any files).
So, if any of my project files (like, at all) contains this pesky BOM, there's a chance it somehow influenced resulting JSON reply?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I was outputting json from PHP and there were other class files included at the top of the page. These files output nothing, but when they were included I was getting as many Byte Order Marks as I had included files. So if I had 4 includes, I also had 4 BOMs at the start of my json.

I made sure the includes were not printing any data and there were no stray carriage returns outside the PHP tags. I tried headers such as "application-json", etc., but nothing worked.

In the end, **I simply opened each PHP file in notepad++, went to "Encoding" and changed it from UTF-8 to ANSI, then saved.** That was all it took to get it working and returning valid json. I made no code changes to the PHP at all.

This solution still feels less than ideal. Since we are not outputting anything from those included files there shouldn't be anything affected.

Comment: That's how PHP interpreter works. Anything that is not within `<?php` and `?>` is being output verbatim. BOM is right at the beginning of the file (3 first bytes), so before `<?php`. That's why it appears, even though no other output is generated in such a file. Remember you can always use PHP to look for BOM in your source files and remove it for you ;)

Comment: Just leave off the PHP closing tag. This also prevents "headers already sent" issues.

Comment: Using "UTF-8 without BOM" will serve you purpose *much* better. You don't want your source code be encoded in an obscure ANSI code page just to remove BOM.